# ClassNotFoundException when starting Jetty 9.0.0.RC1

Tags: configuration, jetty

I cannot start jetty 9 (win 7 x64):

```
java -jar start.jar
```

> 2013-02-26 12:47:49.521:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Config error
> at |        |       java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org
> .eclipse.jetty.util.thread.TimerScheduler.TimerScheduler in file:/C:/Users/Quick
> sort/Desktop/jetty-distribution-9.0.0.RC1/etc/jetty.xml
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:453)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:595)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Timer
> Scheduler.TimerScheduler
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:100)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.nodeClas
> s(XmlConfiguration.java:354)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj(X
> mlConfiguration.java:743)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.itemValu
> e(XmlConfiguration.java:1111)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.value(Xm
> lConfiguration.java:1016)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.call(Xml
> Configuration.java:710)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configur
> e(XmlConfiguration.java:407)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configur
> e(XmlConfiguration.java:344)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.jav
> a:262)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:12
> 21)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:116
> 0)
> ... 7 more

org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.TimerScheduler.TimerScheduler exists in the lib dir (jetty-util-7.6.9.v20130131.jar comes with the .zip)

This also appends on jetty 7 and 8 when adding these lines in jetty.xml (by default in jetty 9):

```
<Call name="addBean">
    <Arg>
       <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.TimerScheduler.TimerScheduler"/>
    </Arg>
</Call>
```

Any advice ?

**Solved**

---

Now I have another problem (with 9.0.0.RC2)if I add this to my jetty.xml file (from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/using-context-provider.html)):

```
<Ref refid="DeploymentManager">
    <Call name="addAppProvider">
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ContextProvider">
                <Set name="monitoredDir"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/contexts</Set>
                <Set name="scanInterval">1</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>
</Ref>
```

gives:

> 2013-02-26 19:13:56.788:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Config error at |???/contexts1</
> New>|?? java.lang.IllegalStateException: No object for refid=
> DeploymentManager in file:/C:/Users/Quicksort/Desktop/jetty-distribution-9.0.0.R
> C2/etc/jetty.xml
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:453)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:595)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No object for refid=DeploymentManage
> r
> at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.refObj(X
> mlConfiguration.java:818)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configur
> e(XmlConfiguration.java:419)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configur
> e(XmlConfiguration.java:344)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.jav
> a:262)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:12
> 21)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:116
> 0)
> ... 7 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was brought up in the jetty-users mailing list..

http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg03044.html

If you are using the distribution (and not embedded mode use of jetty), then use 9.0.0.RC2.
There are a number of configuration errors in 9.0.0.RC1

Comment: Direct download link for 9.0.0.RC2: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-distribution/9.0.0.RC2/jetty-distribution-9.0.0.RC2.tar.gz